# Use specific build executor for releases in Hudson/Jenkins

Tags: build, hudson, release, phing, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins with Phing to make builds. I have one main build executor (master) and a few other build executors (slaves). Master is much slower than the slaves at building. However, master is the only executor which is able to make release builds.

My question is, how can I get non-release builds to build on the slaves/master and release builds to build only against the master?

Currently I manually change the project config in Jenkins restricting which executor can build the project. I often forget to change this when releasing and so want to avoid having to change the project config every time.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to create two jobs, one for normal development builds, and the other for release builds.

You could also try creating a parameterised build, where the value of the variable is the slave to run the build on - I am not sure if hudson would allow you to put a variable in the "restrict where this project can be run" box though.